# Create multiple tables in a DB previously created

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to search on a scholar subject DB, and when I get the name of the subject, create a new table to save some homework there ( as a list to do) but this will be multiple (a scholar schedule).

I have been trying with on upgrade, I get the name, I create the table, but when I try to add smt it says "no such table" how I can do this?

THANKS A LOT

Answer (score -1):

```
String stm = "CREATE TABLE something (colum1,colum2, ...)";

public void execSQL(String stm) {
    try {
        myDataBase.execSQL(stm);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

After insert your data in your colums. You can always use the same function, just create new statement variable each time you calling it. A simple easy way, not always the best, but it's work well. I suppose you know how to read data in your db. I hope it will help you.